# API call JSON File and create Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, entity-framework, linq

I am wondering how to create a database based off a JSON file. The file I'm working with is:

[JSON file](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/5b3a-rs48/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD)

What I am using is Visual Studio 2015 and MSSQL 2012. A few of the included options I'm using are Entity Framework with MVC and WEB API template. I want to use LINQ, but am lost on how to accomplish that. What I do know is how to make a SQL connection and create a database and tables, and store info. using SQLcommands function.

Questions:

I want to know how to make an API call using jquery (from data.gov) to get the JSON file and create a database schema with the necessary tables from that JSON file provided above. Then use LINQ to create database. OR

If I make the JSON file as a resource to my project and create the database schema and tables, how would I parse that data in correctly using LINQ?

Is there a way to see what kind of tables and columns the JSON file has visually, like a cool software or something?

From there, I will be able to re-populate the same JSON file into a better database design in 3rd normal form (if it's not in that already).

Conclusion:

As mentioned before, I'm using Entity Framework with MVC capabilities that I will custom code specifically for that data with basic CRUD functions.
If I'm unclear or this question is not relevant please comment.

Comment: Is that a standardized JSON format? I've never seen anything like it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of questions.
So here's *some* answers:

**Making an API call:**
([read about data.gov's API](http://www.data.gov/developers/apis))
I'm not familiar with JQuery ([their docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)), but i do know that you can do it with the [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) in C#
Example:

```
var Client = new HttpClient();
string request;
try
{
    using (Client)
    {
        request = await Client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    request = null;
}

return request;
```

The url would be the API call, something like:
http://catalog.data.gov/api/3/?query=blahblah&API_KEY
or
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/5b3a-rs48/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD
The returned request would be your JSON string.

**Parsing JSON:**
 Regarding parsing from JSON to a C# object, you can use a [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can get it in Nuget.
This however requires you to have a class that contains all the properties that the JSON string contains.
Example:

```
var myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomJsonClass>(json);
```

**Creating Class based on provided JSON:**
You can do this in 3 ways *or more..*:
1. Use [Json Utils](http://jsonutils.com/) or [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) or copy the JSON string and go into visual studio and use Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes
2. Write it yourself
3. Use Json Utils [source code](https://github.com/bladefist/JsonUtils) in your project.

Creating the tables (and using LINQ) in Entity Framework can be done by using your new class based on your JSON string ([Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx))

This is very unclear:
*Is there a way to see what kind of tables and columns the JSON file has visually, like a cool software or something?*
If you mean after you've created a table in a SQL database and put in the values, yes. You should be able to use Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you so much Cicero. I will try what you have suggested and update you on my progress.

Comment: I have been working with your post and everything works great so far, thanks again. I haven't found a problem with your answer yet, so I marked it as the answer.

Comment: @Roys Thanks and you're welcome. I'm glad it worked. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Out of curiosity though in an MVC (Entity Framework) design where is the best place to put the code for the API call? I just put it in an empty created controller.

Comment: @Roys Use a controller to do the API calls and use your EF [database context](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx) inside the controller to save the data to the database. After you've converted it to the proper object of course. That should be sufficient. But it's really a matter of what you think works best.